# MySQL Group By Query X or not X

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This should be easy but I have not found the answer. I have a query that is running a count and I want to group this within the query into those where State = 1 and State <>1 and have the sum for each group.

```
SELECT count(`id_job`) as count, `state` 
FROM job_table 
GROUP BY `state`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query a boolean expression and group by it too:

```
SELECT   state = 1, COUNT(*)
FROM     job_table
GROUP BY state = 1
```

Comment: This worked best once I included some of the other Query requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(id_job) as count,state FROM job_table 
  GROUP BY case when state = 1 then 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can easily put these into columns:

```
select sum( state = 1 ) as state_1,
       sum( state <> 1 ) as state_2
from job_table;
```

If `state` can be `NULL`, you want to be a bit careful.  The second condition is safer as:

```
select sum( state = 1 ) as state_1,
       sum( not state <=> 1 ) as state_2
from job_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN State=1 THEN 1 END) as count1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN State<>1 THEN 1 END) as count2,
       State
FROM job_table 
GROUP BY state
```